# How to import my own android application project into IBM Bluemix?

Tags: java, android, cloud, ibm-cloud

Can someone help me use the new PaaS - IBM Bluemix?

I faced a dilemma that I want to import my android application project which was developed on my local computer into the IBM Bluemix and run on the platform ,but I didn't know how to use it.

I have search on Internet about this ,I still cannot find the solution.

Does IBM Bluemix support this kind of service?

I just want to debug or test on this cloud platform.

Comment: are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You don't deploy an android application to bluemix as the android application exists on the actual mobile device (or emulator) and not in the cloud. What Bluemix offers you is the ability to have services running on the cloud that can work with your android application on the mobile device. This is called MBaaS (Mobile Backend as a Service).

For example you can have a MobileData service that allows you to store data in the cloud that your mobile device(s) (iOS, android or web) can access (think of having a game save that can then be picked up by another user device to resume playing at the same point). Bluemix provides an SDK to access these services on Bluemix from your android application source code.

Answer (score 2):

IBM Bluemix is a cloud platform where you can build web applications / mobile back end services utilizing a wide range of services.

Lets say you are building a  weather app. This app will require two components 
1. a server side web application 
2. a mobile application (lets say android)

The server side component does only one thing, it constantly collects weather forecast from multiple data sources (eg www.data.gov, forecast.io etc). This app has restful apis exposed to internet which can be invoked by mobile app to request weather forecast for a particular geo cordinates (E.g http://weatherapp.mybluemix.net/getForcast/122.20,-100.20). The server app responds to get requests in JSON format.

The Mobile app, detects current location's geo co-ordinate using mobile phone's GPS and request weather forecast of the location from server component using a HTTP get (GET:http://weatherapp.mybluemix.net/getForcast/122.20,-100.20) . The mobile app then parse the response JSON data and display information on a neat elegant screen.

If you want to port this app onto IBM bluemix, you can build the server component using, NOde.js or JSP or PHP etc, use mMongoDB,mySQL DB or Postgresql databases, use twillio for text messaging/mms or voice call, use IBM Push for notifying user about weather forecast etc.

Using Android SDK, IBM Cloud services SDk (Mobile data, push notification etc) and sell it on Google play.

Hope this helps
-Keep coding-

Answer (score 0):

We have sample applications for Bluemix which can be deployed on Android.  See the "boilerplate" app in the Bluemix catalog named "Mobile Cloud".  Head to the Bluemix console [1], click on "CATALOG" at the top.  The Mobile Cloud docs [2] reference several applications for iOS, Android, etc with server-side pieces can be deployed on Bluemix.

[1] https://bluemix.net/

[2] https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/mobile/index.html

Answer (score 0):

you can refer [developerwork article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-android-push-app/) to get started to use Bluemix services for your andriod app.

Answer (score 0):

First ,you need to login to bluemix and create a new account in ther,
There u have create an application in ur dashboard,where the runtimes in node.js,and add the following services namely,push,mobile data and mobile security application.
Then u need to download the android SDK available in it and add to ur  android app all the jar files in the libs folder.
U need to save the app id,secret id and the link in order to connect it from local android app to bluemix.

Hope this was useful,if any doubt further,let me know